# refreshing view controller on return

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a view controller that displays some amount of data. When a user clicks on a button, they are taken to `UITableViewController`. I then have a "barbuttonitem" that uses
 `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` to go back to the previous view controller with the data. The problem is that the data on the previous controller is supposed to change when I return back to it through a method I'm declaring in `viewDidLoad`. However, the data stays the same. Any idea why this could be?

**For example:** If the text label says "3 notifications", and the users clicks on the button to go to the `UITableViewController` and then clicks the back button, it is supposed to say 0 notifications.

Comment: viewDidLoad is only called once in the lifetime of a controller -- it will not be called again when you dismiss your modal controller.

Comment: so what is the solution? every time I try to create a segue from the barbuttonitem to the view controller, it says "unrecognized selector sent to instance" but im not sure why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your logic in viewWillAppear. when you push a newViewController the oldViewController is still in memory but not in screen, viewWillAppear will be called when go back (back button)

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Instead of

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

**viewDidLoad** is called one time, when the view controller is loaded the first time. **viewDidAppear** is called every time your view is displayed at the hierarchy.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working...the method is actually in -(void)loadView if that helps